# Why does $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ for all $n \geq 1$ if $|f^{(n)}(x)| \leq \frac{1}{R^n}$ and $R \to \infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Claim:

> If for all $z \in B(a, R)$ we have $|f(z)| < 1$, then by Cauchy's estimate we have $|f^{(n)}(a)| \le \frac {n!}{R^n}$ for all $R > 0$. If $R \to \infty$, then $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n \geq 1$.

I want to know why for all $n \geq 1$, and not for all $n \geq 0$, or any other integer such as $n \geq 42$.

Comment: What does the estimation lemma give for Cauchy integral formula? Look closely at how the length of the curve behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=0$ the inequality reads
$$
|f(0)|\le1.
$$
From here you cannot conclude that $f(0)=0$. An example would be the constant function $f(z)=1/2$.

If $n\ge1$, taking limits as $R\to\infty$ you get $f^{(n)}(0)=0$. Since $42>1$, if $n\ge42$ it is also $\ge1$, so the conclusion holds.